# Query to split row into multiple row according to date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to create one query to split the start and end date by day if the range is over 1 day.
My query will return multiple row and each row have their own start date time and end date time

Example:

**Scenario 1 - Row 1 raw data as below :**

```
Start Date Time           END Date time
2022-08-16 16:19:05.550   2022-08-16 16:19:24.093
```

**Expected output is only 1 row as below:**

```
Start Date time           End Date Time
2022-08-16 16:19:05.550   2022-08-16 16:19:24.093
```

My Query below able to achieve this Scenario 1.

**Scenario  2- Row 2 raw data as below :**

```
Start Date Time          END Date time
2022-08-17 14:22:56.277  2022-08-19 15:02:41.523
```

**Expected Output will have 3 rows as below:**

```
Start Date time 2022-08-**17** 14:22:56.277, End Date Time 2022-08-**17 23:59:59.000**   
Start Date time 2022-08-**17** 00:00:00.000, End Date Time 2022-08-**18 23:59:59.000**   
Start Date time >2022-08-**18** 00:00:00.000, End Date Time 2022-08-**19 15:02:41.523**
```

**My Query below NOT able to achieve this Scenario.**

```
WITH date_range_cte AS (
SELECT 
    CLOCKING_ID, 
    CAST(START_DATE_TIME AS datetime) AS START_DATE_TIME,
    CAST(END_DATE_TIME AS datetime) AS END_DATE_TIME,
    CAST(START_DATE_TIME AS date) AS START_DATE,
    CAST(END_DATE_TIME AS date) AS END_DATE
FROM [time_tbl] 
WHERE ID = 18
    AND END_DATE_TIME IS NOT NULL 
    AND START_DATE_TIME IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CLOCKING_ID, 
    DATEADD(day, 1, START_DATE_TIME) AS START_DATE_TIME,
    END_DATE_TIME,
    DATEADD(day, 1, START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
    END_DATE AS END_DATE
FROM date_range_cte
WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, START_DATE) <= END_DATE
) SELECT 
    CLOCKING_ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN START_DATE = CAST(START_DATE_TIME AS date) AND END_DATE = CAST(END_DATE_TIME AS date) THEN START_DATE_TIME 
        WHEN START_DATE = CAST(START_DATE_TIME AS date) THEN START_DATE_TIME
        ELSE CAST(START_DATE AS datetime) + CAST('00:00:00.000' AS datetime)
    END AS START_DATE_TIME,
    CASE 
        WHEN START_DATE = CAST(START_DATE_TIME AS date) AND END_DATE = CAST(END_DATE_TIME AS date) THEN END_DATE_TIME
        WHEN END_DATE = CAST(END_DATE_TIME AS date) THEN END_DATE_TIME
        ELSE CAST(END_DATE AS datetime) + CAST('23:59:59.000' AS datetime)
    END AS END_DATE_TIME
FROM date_range_cte
ORDER BY START_DATE_TIME
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Above is the code that I tried. But the result is not as expected
Result as below:
[image]
Suppose for ID 112, start date is correct, but time is incorrect, end date time both incorrect.
ID 112 raw data is START DATE TIME: 2022-08-17 14:22:56.277 , END DATE TIME: 2022-08-22 15:02:41.523

Comment: I think I'd start from a calendar table base query then join to your data where the date matches to get the right rows.   Then do a CASE to check which date (calendar table, or your data date) is earliest to get the Start Date Time, and do the same to find the latest date from the two dates to get the End date time.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

With your example data as input:

| Id | StartDT | EndDT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 2022-08-16 16:19:05.550 | 2022-08-16 16:19:24.093 |
| 112 | 2022-08-17 14:22:56.277 | 2022-08-19 15:02:41.523 |

Query:

```
SELECT  T.Id,
        CASE
            WHEN numbers.[Value] = 0
            THEN T.StartDT
            ELSE CAST(DATEADD(DAY, numbers.[Value], T.StartDT) AS DATE)
        END AS NewStartDT,
        CASE
            WHEN numbers.[Value] = DATEDIFF(DAY, T.StartDT, T.EndDT)
            THEN T.EndDT
            ELSE DATEADD(SECOND, -1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, numbers.[Value] + 1, T.StartDT) AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
        END AS NewEndDT
FROM    time_tbl AS T
JOIN    GENERATE_SERIES(0, 100, 1) AS numbers
    ON  numbers.[Value] <= DATEDIFF(DAY, T.StartDT, T.EndDT)
```

Result:

| Id | NewStartDT | NewEndDT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 2022-08-16 16:19:05.550 | 2022-08-16 16:19:24.093 |
| 112 | 2022-08-17 14:22:56.277 | 2022-08-17 23:59:59.000 |
| 112 | 2022-08-18 00:00:00.000 | 2022-08-18 23:59:59.000 |
| 112 | 2022-08-19 00:00:00.000 | 2022-08-19 15:02:41.523 |

**

If your version of sql server doesn't support GENERATE_SERIES() function,

you can use instead the system "spt_values" table, like this:

```
SELECT  T.Id,
        CASE
            WHEN numbers.number = 0
            THEN T.StartDT
            ELSE CAST(DATEADD(DAY, numbers.number, T.StartDT) AS DATE)
        END AS NewStartDT,
        CASE
            WHEN numbers.number = DATEDIFF(DAY, T.StartDT, T.EndDT)
            THEN T.EndDT
            ELSE DATEADD(SECOND, -1, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, numbers.number + 1, T.StartDT) AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
        END AS NewEndDT
FROM    time_tbl AS T
JOIN    master..spt_values  AS numbers
    ON  numbers.type = 'p'
    AND numbers.number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, T.StartDT, T.EndDT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using an ad-hoc Tally/Numbers table and a `CROSS APPLY` to calculate the `nDays`.   The beginning/end just becomes a small matter of a CASE expression

You may notice I used TOP 1000 for the ad-hoc numbers table.  Feel free to adjust to a more reasonable number.

You may also notice I added the milliseconds of 997 rather than using 000.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Clocking_ID] int,[Start_Date_Time] datetime,[END_Date_Time] datetime)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (99,'2022-08-16 16:19:05.550','2022-08-16 16:19:24.093')
,(112,'2022-08-17 14:22:56.277','2022-08-19 15:02:41.523')

 
Select A.[Clocking_ID]
      ,Beg_Date_Time = case when N     = 0 then [Start_Date_Time] else convert(date,dateadd(day,N,[Start_Date_Time])) end
      ,End_Date_Time = case when nDays = N then [END_Date_Time]   else left(convert(date,dateadd(day,N,[Start_Date_Time])),10)+' 23:59:59.997' end
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( datediff(day, [Start_Date_Time],[END_Date_Time]) ) ) B(nDays)
 Join  ( Select Top 1000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2  ) C
   on  N<= nDays
```

**Results**

[image]